# net core api and vue js SPA keycloak authentification

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, keycloak, openid

I am using net core for my back-end rest api and vuejs for the front-end.
I made an authentication via a cookie

I want to authenticate via keycloak. I want authentication to go through keycloak's authentication page and not my app's (vueJs) authentication page.

I haven't been able to find any sample code to do this.

If I do the authentication via VueJS, how then do I do so that the authentication is done on the net core API (sending the token to the API or other)?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes i add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

I added this in the Startup.cs file:

```
private static bool ServerCertificateCustomValidation(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslErrors)
    {
        //It is possible inpect the certificate provided by server
        Log($"Requested URI: {requestMessage.RequestUri}");
        Log($"Effective date: {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()}");
        Log($"Exp date: {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
        Log($"Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
        Log($"Subject: {certificate.Subject}");

        //Based on the custom logic it is possible to decide whether the client considers certificate valid or not
        Log($"Errors: {sslErrors}");

        return true;
        //return sslErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
            o.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
            o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            o.SaveToken = true;


            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                CheckCertificateRevocationList = false,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => ServerCertificateCustomValidation(message, cert, chain, errors),
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                //ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator,
                //ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; },
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
            };
            //HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            //handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
            handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
            o.BackchannelHttpHandler = handler;

            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "preferred_username"
            };

            o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {
                OnTokenValidated = c =>
                {
                    var test = c;

                    /*ClaimsIdentity identity = c.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    identity.Se*/
                    JwtSecurityToken accessToken = c.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                    if (accessToken != null)
                    {
                        ClaimsIdentity identity = c.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                        if (identity != null)
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken.RawData));
                        }
                    }
                    //c.NoResult();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                {
                    c.NoResult();

                    Log($"test");

                    c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    //if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                    //{
                    //return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
                    //}
                    return c.Response.WriteAsync("An error occured processing your authentication." + c.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
            };
        });

        ...
        services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
        });

        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
            });
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp";
        });
    }
```

And in appsettings.json :

```
"Jwt": {
"Authority": "https://auth.myauthority/auth/realms/myauthority",
"https": null,
"Audience": "MyAudience"
```

},

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).